# Drop Down Menu using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, drop-down-menu

function.php

```
 function getCategories($id = null) {
      $categoried = array();

       $query = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM `categories`");

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
              $categories [] = $row;
     }
```

dropdown.php

```
...
             <select name="category">
                  <?php 
                     foreach(getCategories() as $category){
                  ?>
                  <option value=" <?php echo $category['id'];?> " > <?php echo $category['name'];?> </option>
                  <?php
    }
    ?>
```

I am trying to use a drop down menu, but it seems like I can't figure out on how to populate the drop-down menu with items from mySql database. The code above doesn't fill my drop down menu. So can someone tell me where I have made the mistake

Comment: don't use mysql_* is bester to use mysqli_* ...check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the `$categories` array from your function:

```
function getCategories() {
    $categories = array();
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM `categories`");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
        $categories[] = $row;
    }

    return $categories; // return the results array
}
```

Returning an array in a function makes the execution of the function interchangeable with arrays in expressions, such as `foreach ( $array as $value ) {`. In place of `$array` you can put a function that returns an array: `foreach ( returnsArray() as $value ) {`. In this case: `foreach ( getCategories() as $category) {`.

Comment: And, yes, PHP `mysql_*` functions are **deprecated**. More secure options available.